# EF Core - Computed Column of Foreign Match Count

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

Say I have a Query like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
       [Apps].Id,
       [Apps].Name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [DbName].[dbo].[Requests] Requests WHERE [Apps].Id = [Requests].AppId) as PendingRequests
  FROM [DbName].[dbo].[Apps] Apps
```

Is there a way to map this count column without using a Stored Procedure?

I've tried something like this, which didn't seem to work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AppModel>()
    .Property(m => m.PendingRequests)
    .HasComputedColumnSql(
        "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Requests] " +
        "WHERE [Apps].[Id] = [Requests].[AppId]) as PendingRequests"
    );
```

I could just use the populated `IEnumerable` of foreign objects to check the `Count()`, but that for obvious reasons wouldn't be very performant with lists of the parent object.

Any tips?

Comment: is this code first or database first? database first should be able.

Comment: @BagusTesa it's code first

Comment: Hi @afollestad, see Thomas Koelle's answer. sorry, i assumed you want to run a stored procedure. EF only support database first for stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ofcourse do the mapping within the query:

```
from row in _db.Apps select new App() {
                     Id = row.Id
                     PendingRequests = row.Requests.Count()
                     }
```

I assume you have set up FKs correct so the navigational properties work.

Comment: Wow, simpler than I'd expect. Thanks!